# How to compare each Scrapy spider item with another Scrapy spider items?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need a solution to compare each item of `SecondSpider` with all items of `FirstSpider`. Check out this dummy code.

```
class FirstSpider(Spider):
    all_items = []

    def parse(self, response):
        trs = response.xpath("table tr")
        for tr in trs:
            item = SomeItem()
            item["one"] = "one"
            yield item

class SecondSpider(Spider):
    def parse(self, response):
        trs = response.xpath("table tr")
        for tr in trs:
            item = SomeItem()
            item["one"] = "one"
            if item in FirstSpider.all_items:
                yield item
```

Thanks!

Comment: write each to separate files and use the utility `diff`? Otherwise you probably need to include small sample inputs and required output based on those inputs. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your spiders run one after the other: `FirstSpider` collects all the data then you run `SecondSpider`. In this case one solution would be to save all the items returned by `FirstSpider` to a temporal file then read it in when you initialize `SecondSpider`. In this case you have access to all the data locally and can filter for it.

Alternatively you can create an item pipeline which loads the exported items from `FirstSpider` and does the filtering of the items returned by `SecondSpider`.